# display in table form

Tags: java

hi this is my code to calculate term frequency.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the required word  :");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = scan.nextLine();
    String[] array = word.split(" ");
    int filename = 11;
    String[] fileName = new String[filename];
    int a = 0;

    for (a = 0; a < filename; a++) {
        try {
            File file = new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc" + a
                            + ".txt");
            System.out.println("File = abc" + a + ".txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                System.out.println(array[i]);

                int totalCount = 0;
                int wordCount = 0;
                int numDoc2 = 0;

                Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
                {
                    while (s.hasNext()) {
                        totalCount++;
                        if (s.next().equals(array[i]))
                            wordCount++;

                    }

                    System.out.println("Word count:  " + wordCount);
                    System.out.println("Total count: " + totalCount);
                    System.out.printf("Term Frequency:   %8.4f",
                            (double) wordCount / totalCount);

                    System.out.println("\n");

                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File is not found");

        }

    }
```

so far the code display

Please enter the required word  :
about

File = abc0.txt

about

Word count:  0

Total count: 1706

Term Frequency:     0.0000

File = abc1.txt

about

Word count:  0

Total count: 9819

Term Frequency:     0.0000

how do i create a data table form which is like this :

OUTPUT :

filename     word      total     term

abc0.txt      0.1      0.2        0.3

abc1.txt      0.4      0.5        0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `System.out.println(String)`, use `System.out.print(String)`.

`System.out.print(String)` will print out the data without causing the following `System.out.print(String)` to start on the next line. This will help you get the data output in the correct format

Change the print statement for the file name at the top to

```
System.out.print("abc" + a + ".txt");
```

AND Change the print statements at the end to

```
System.out.print(" " + wordCount);
System.out.print(" " + totalCount);
System.out.printf(" %8.4f", (double) wordCount / totalCount);
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.out.print();` in-place of `System.out.println();` and provide proper TABs by "\t"

**Example:**
See difference in each case

```
System.out.print("Hello ");  
System.out.print("World");    
//output: Hello World

System.out.println("Hello ");  
System.out.println("World");    
//output: 
     Hello 
     World
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.out.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), it uses a [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) internally.